# How can I center the sub-list items like the example image?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying figure out how to center the below nested lists. At the moment I'm using margin and padding to push the list items across.

The nested lists are displayed when hovering over the parent list item. The nested list items are displayed as inline-flex as inline-block doesn't in this example for some reason.

example image of what I'd 
[image]

```css
  #nav {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  text-align: center; /* centers 1st level list items but not 2nd level(?)*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-inline-start: 0px; /* override chrome user agent style of 40px */
}


/*1st level li styling */

.nav-tab {
  border: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #F8F8F8;
  padding: 0 40px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #707070;
}

.nav-tab:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}


/*2nd level ul styling */

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute; /* drops submenu below tabs */
  display: none;      /* hides submenu */
  list-style-type: none; /* removes bullet points */
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 25px;
  border: white;
  min-width: 100%; /* li stretches % of length of parent element */
  left: 380px;     /* an attempt to push the first list item across the page */
}

li .sub-nav-link {
  text-decoration: none; /* removes underline on links */
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #707070;
  margin-right: 120px; /* an attempt to push the 2nd, 3rd, ..  list items further across the page */
}

li:hover>.dropdown-content {
  display: inline-flex; /* inline-block didnt work for me here(?) - but inline-flex did */
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav" id="primary-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-tab">Products
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Range</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Catalogue</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">About Us
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Background</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Production</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">Events
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">Stockists
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">Contact
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Details</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[a JSFiddle to play with my code](https://jsfiddle.net/SDSmith/87dr0pgu/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the top level ul relative and keep the parent li non positioned, then you can absolutely position the child ul to take the full width and centre align the children:

```css
#nav {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  text-align: center; /* centers 1st level list items but not 2nd level(?)*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-inline-start: 0px; /* override chrome user agent style of 40px */
  
  position:relative;  /* ADD THIS */
}

/*1st level li styling */
.nav-tab {
  border: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #F8F8F8;
  padding: 0 40px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #707070;
}

.nav-tab:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

/*2nd level ul styling */
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute; /* drops submenu below tabs */
  list-style-type: none; /* removes bullet points */
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 25px;
  border: white;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:none;
  text-align:center;
  left: 0; 
  right:0;   /* stretch content full width of ul with left and right */
  top:100%;  /* push content below current ul */
}

.dropdown-content > li {
    display:inline-block; /* so they centre */
    margin:0 1em;         /* space between each item */
}

li .sub-nav-link {
  text-decoration: none; /* removes underline on links */
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #707070;
}

li:hover>.dropdown-content {
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav" id="primary-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-tab">Products
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Range</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Catalogue</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">About Us
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Background</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Production</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">Events
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">Stockists
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">Contact
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Details</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 #nav {
      margin: 0;
    }

    ul {
      background: #F8F8F8;
      text-align: center; /* centers 1st level list items but not 2nd level(?)*/
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding-inline-start: 0px; /* override chrome user agent style of 40px */
    }

    /*1st level li styling */
    .nav-tab {
      border: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
      border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
      display: inline-block;
      background: #F8F8F8;
      padding: 0 40px;
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #707070;
    }

    .nav-tab:hover {
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid white;
      border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    }

    /*2nd level ul styling */
    .dropdown-content {
      position: absolute; /* drops submenu below tabs */
      display: none; /* hides submenu */
      list-style-type: none; /* removes bullet points */
      background: white;
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      font-size: 25px;
      border: white;
      min-width: 100%; /* li stretches % of length of parent element */
      left: 0; /* an attempt to push the first list item towards the middle of the page */
    }

    li .sub-nav-link {
      text-decoration: none; /* removes underline on links */
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #707070;
      margin-right: 120px; /* an attempt to push the 2nd, 3rd, ..  list items further across the page */
    }
    
    .dropdown-content li{display: inline-block}

    li:hover>.dropdown-content {
      display: block; /* inline-block didnt work for me here(?) - but inline-flex did */
```

```html
<nav class="nav" id="primary-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-tab">Products
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Range</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Catalogue</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">About Us
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Background</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Production</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">Events
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">Stockists
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">Contact
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Details</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I positioned the submenu at the left and use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to center the content. Also documented in the CSS code.

```css
  #nav {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  text-align: center;
  /* centers 1st level list items but not 2nd level(?)*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-inline-start: 0px;
  /* override chrome user agent style of 40px */
}


/*1st level li styling */

.nav-tab {
  border: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #F8F8F8;
  padding: 0 40px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #707070;
}

.nav-tab:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}


/*2nd level ul styling */

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  /* drops submenu below tabs */
  display: none;
  /* hides submenu */
  list-style-type: none;
  /* removes bullet points */
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 25px;
  border: white;
  min-width: 100%; /* li stretches % of length of parent element */
  /* left: 380px;  an attempt to push the first list item across the page */
  left: 0; /* ADDED */
}

li .sub-nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  /* removes underline on links */
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #707070;
  margin-right: 120px;
  /* an attempt to push the 2nd, 3rd, ..  list items further across the page */
}

li:hover>.dropdown-content {
  /* display: inline-flex;  inline-block didnt work for me here(?) - but inline-flex did */
  display: flex; /* ADDED */
  justify-content: center; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav" id="primary-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-tab">Products
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Range</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Catalogue</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">About Us
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Background</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Production</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">Events
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">Stockists
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-tab">Contact
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Details</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```